# biopython - Entrez.esearch() query translation does not correspond my query

Tags: python, biopython

I'm new to Biopython. Using this code:

```
handle = Entrez.esearch(db="nuccore", term="complete", field="title", FILT="refseq", porgn="viruses", rettype='xml')
print Entrez.read(handle)[u'QueryTranslation']
```

I get:

```
complete[Title]
```

but I'm expecting sth like this:

```
complete[Title] AND "viruses"[porgn]
```

(QueryTranslation from search results on http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore)

The refseq filter also seems not to work. What am I doing wrong?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the current NCBI documentation, there are no options FILT or progrn - the NCBI is probably silently ignoring them (personally I'd prefer an explicit error message from them).

Based on the http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK25499/#chapter4.ESearch you can now do

```
>>> from Bio import Entrez
>>> handle = Entrez.esearch(db="nuccore", term="complete", field="title", rettype='xml')
>>> print Entrez.read(handle)[u'QueryTranslation']
complete[Title]
```

as an alternative to:

```
>>> from Bio import Entrez
>>> handle = Entrez.esearch(db="nuccore", term="complete[title]", rettype='xml')
>>> print Entrez.read(handle)[u'QueryTranslation']
complete[Title]
```

That field option is (I'm petty sure) a new feature from the NCBI, but doesn't actually add any new functionality. It would seem to only make sense for trivial searches.

In order to do the complex search you appear to want, do this:

```
>>> from Bio import Entrez
>>> handle = Entrez.esearch(db="nuccore", term="complete[title] AND viruses[porgn]", rettype='xml')
>>> print Entrez.read(handle)[u'QueryTranslation']
complete[title] AND viruses[porgn]
```

There are examples like this in the Biopython Tutorial. See also http://news.open-bio.org/news/2009/06/ncbi-einfo-biopython/ (also now in the Biopython Tutorial).

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to edit your `term` key word argument. You need to include `AND viruses[porgn]`

```
>>> handle = Entrez.esearch(db="nuccore", term="complete AND viruses[porgn]", field="title", FILT="refseq", rettype='xml')
>>> print Entrez.read(handle)[u'QueryTranslation']
complete[Title] AND viruses[porgn]
```

Comment: Yeah, it wokrs, but i don't understand Biopython developers "politics". It seems that only two of arguments passed to Entrez.esearch (db and term) are paseed further to eutils. So why did they leave the possibility to pass another arguments to Entrez.esearch?

Comment: The old NCBI documentation isn't online anymore, but I'm pretty sure "field" is a new option - but as their documentation explains, is just an alternative to including [field] in the search term. And Biopython *is* passing the extra arguments to ESearch.

Answer (score 0):

To add the RefSeq requirement too, you can do

```
>>> from Bio import Entrez
>>> handle = Entrez.esearch(db="nuccore", term="complete[title] AND refeq[filter] AND viruses[porgn]", rettype='xml')
```